# Image height within absolute div?

Tags: css, safari, height, css-position, absolute

Safari for Windows is not calculating img height correctly within absolutely positioned div. The styling works fine on Chrome and Firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/Wh2Tr/

HTML:

```
<div class="image">
  <div class="image-inner">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 75%;
}

.image-inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}

.image img {
    width: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Caveats:

1. This is a simplification of the HTML. There are multiple images of varying sizes which need to have the same height (so using width:100%;height:auto; won't work)
2. This needs to be adaptive/responsive, so I can't set an explicit width or height to the image or container.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, I've used jquery. I couldn't find any solution till now:

```
$('.image-inner').css('height','100%').height($('.image-inner').height());
```

Answer (score 0):

On the class image put height to auto. That should fix it. http://jsfiddle.net/Wh2Tr/1/

```
.image {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 75%;
}
```

Comment: Can't. I need to maintain a consistent height for the image (which gets switched out via JS but isn't necessary to demonstrate the problem).

Comment: Ok, well then set a height and width to the element

Comment: Your question didn't explain that you needed that.

Comment: You're right that I didn't explain I needed that. I thought it would be silly to say that I tried the obvious or easier solutions. I also should have mentioned it must be responsive, which is why everything is in % and no width and height are set.